# Excel: Referenced cell moving positions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if it was possible to reference a cell in another sheet and whenever the source cell changes positions the referenced cell changes positions too. I tried linked pictures but because I have a lot of data it slowed my workbook down quite a bit. So I am doing things like this:

```
Sheet1      Sheet2
Name        ='Sheet1'!$A1
```

While this gets the data I want, whenever I move A1 on Sheet1, the referenced cell doesn't move positions. Is there something else I need to add to the formula?

Comment: what you are describing does not sound right.  When you click on a cell in sheet2 and start a formula with = you should then be able to click on a cell in sheet1 then hit enter and you should have results as described above.   When you click on the cell in sheet 1 it will highlight.  if you click and hold the side or top borders you should be able to drag the cell around.  Conversely if you select row 1 by click on 1 on the left side or A at the top and then proceed to insert rows/column  The cells in the remainder of the sheet should be moved.  Either way the location of A1 is now something

Comment: else.  Your formula in sheet2 should update automatically.  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @ForwardEd Maybe I didnt explain it well enough. Moving it in sheet1 isnt the problem. If I move Names in sheet1 down 3 cells, I would like the referenced cell in sheet2 to move down 3 cells as well.

Comment: as in the value in Sheet 1 a1 is name, and then you place name in sheet 1 a4 and then you delete it from A1?  so cell A1 never moved, but the value it held is now somewhere else?

Comment: So you're trying to tie your formula in Sheet2 to a value rather than a cell?  I don't think there's a good way to do that.  Maybe reconsider how you're managing Sheet1 to prevent this issue instead?  Could you share a bit more info about the overall goal of this formula and workbook?  Maybe that would help generate some other solutions.

Comment: @ForwardEd The purpose of the sheet is to perform functions like this. I just need their locations to be in sync, as in updated every time the source changes its cell location. but if there isnt a way to do this then that is also fine

Comment: normally if its based on where a value is I would be using something like index/match combo, or vlookup depending.  INDEX is supposed to return the cell reference of where you are pointing.

Comment: This might be achievable with a macro, but typical spreadsheets are designed specifically to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a **range name** on the source sheet.  For example, I have a range name called "Whatever" on source sheet and the target sheet has a formula as `=SourceSheet.xlsx!Whatever`.  The target sheet will always point to that range name no matter how you move the cell in the source sheet.